# Turn off the display on remote PC

Tags: c++, windows, drivers, ioctl

I'm fixing some bugs in the application for remote control (remote desktop-like) for Windows.
And there is a feature that you can blank screen on remote machine - all the programms keep running unaffected, but the person who looks into the display on remote PC sees nothing but black screen.

It is implemented by sending IoCtl request `IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_OUTPUT_DEVICE_POWER_STATE`, which is undocumented. And this request does not work on Vista and above.

Are there another ways to do what I want?

In fact, `SendMessage(-1,WM_SOMMAND,SC_MONITORPOWER,2)` does the trick, but screen turns back on if someone toches keyboard/mouse.

Comment: No, the user is always in control.  What are you trying to hide?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send a [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(VS.85).aspx) with the SC_MONITORPOWER set to 2. Unfortunately, I am not at a computer with testing abilities, so I haven't tried it out.

I believe that whenever you touch mouse/keyboard, windows tries to wake up again, but you should be able to trap those messages and resend the 2.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (msg){
        ...
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            switch (wParam){
                case SC_MONITORPOWER:
                return 2;
            }
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Please note that this is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a low level keyboard and mouse hook (which a remote desktop app should already have). Make sure it is low level i.e. [SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx) and SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL).

Inside your hook callback functions:

- DO NOT CALL CallNextHookEx()
- **return -1** in LowLevelKeyboardProc (which you must implement). Do the same thing for LowLevelMouseProc.

**WARNING**: This WILL disable the keyboard (even if it doesn't work properly) until your code does call CallNextHookEx() and returns 0 in your callback procedures.